# Possible to repair this retaining wall?

Tags: repair, cinderblock, retaining-wall, frost

My wife and I are replacing the deck at the back of our house, and after we demolished the existing structure found the retaining walls near our basement door have moved significantly. These are rendered cinder block, about 6' in height and 7' (left) and 9' (right) in length.

It appears as if the previous owners failed to maintain the surface, and water got in... Over several winters the freeze/thaw cycle has caused a heave.

So... Any advice? We will obviously seal the surface where the cracks are, but are there any techniques to repair this heave without replacing the walls?

Left wall: 
[image]
Right Wall: 
[image]

Comment: It depends on what "repair" means; I doubt you'd be able to move the walls back into line.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to either replace the wall or build another new wall behind the original, thus rendering the old wall obsolete. Also there is a lot more to it than that, but this is the simplest way to answer it.